# Can Verisign/Authorize.Net split a transaction into more than account?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net, verisign, merchant-account

I wonder if its possible to have logic where for every transaction 10% goes to a different account. It does not have to be Verisign, or Authorize.Net even, but whatever it is has to be a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now you the only payment option that allows you to split payments is [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro). Verisign, Authorize.Net, and other similar payment gateways do not offer this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at our product, [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com) which is designed specifically for this task.

The core concept is that debits (money in from buyers), and credits (money out to your sellers) are split into two separate transactions which means you can debit a buyer, and then create two (or one, or three...) separate credits to pay the resulting money. This typically would be two credits, one for your seller and a second for yourself to collect a fee, however you could split it further.